# MS Graph works in debug mode, but not in production

Tags: c#, asp.net, microsoft-graph-api, production-environment

I'm developing a job function to get documents from OneDrive in ASP.NET on my website and it's working in debug normally. But when I put it in production, it doesn't work, it also doesn't return any error message which I found strange.

After putting several functions in the code I found out it's stopping is this part shown here:

```
public async Task<IList<DriveItem>> GetFoldersAsync(string folderId)
{
        try
        {
            //in this part he calls the drivers that the job stops
            IDriveItemChildrenCollectionPage drives = await _graphClient.Me.Drive.Items[folderId].Children
                .Request()
                .WithMaxRetry(1)
                .GetAsync();

            List<DriveItem> driveItems = new List<DriveItem>();

            while (drives.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DriveItem item in drives.CurrentPage)
                {
                    PortalERP.Util.SaveException(new Exception("foreach"));

                    if (item.Folder != null)
                    {
                        driveItems.Add(item);
                    }
                }

                if (drives.NextPageRequest != null)
                {
                    drives = await drives.NextPageRequest
                        .WithMaxRetry(10)
                        .GetAsync();
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return driveItems;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            PortalERP.Util.SaveException(e);
            throw;
        }
}
```

I imagine that he is not able to make the connection with Azure, but I don't know why, I saw a similar problem here, but in this person's case it is because he used the `DefaultAzureCredential()` function of `Azure.Identity`, in my case I am not using this function here below is how the code in the construction of the `MsGraphApiService` is being made

```
public MsGraphApiService(OneDriveConfig onedrive)
{
    using (var db = new PortalContext(false))
    {
        if (onedrive != null)
        {
            string[] scopes = onedrive.Scopes.Split(';');

            var tokenOptions = new TokenCachePersistenceOptions() { Name = "token2" };

            var options = new UsernamePasswordCredentialOptions()
                {
                    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
                    TokenCachePersistenceOptions = tokenOptions,
                };

            UsernamePasswordCredential usernamePasswordCredential = new UsernamePasswordCredential(onedrive.UserName,
                             AzureKeyVaultClient.GetSecret(onedrive.SecretAzurePassword),
                             onedrive.TenantId,
                             onedrive.ClientId,
                             options);

            _comprovanteFolderId = onedrive.ComprovanteFolderId;
            _retornoFolderId = onedrive.RetornoFolderId;

            _graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(usernamePasswordCredential, scopes);
        }
    }
}
```

I want some light on what might be going on and how I might be able to resolve it, thanks.